# @reach/router nested protected route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, reach-router

I use reach/router with custom protected route like this :

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  localStorage.getItem('user_id') ? <Component {...rest} /> : <Redirect from="" to="/login" noThrow />
);

const LoginRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  localStorage.getItem('user_id') ? <Redirect from="" to="/home" noThrow /> : <Component {...rest} />
);

const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Component {...rest} />
);

<Router>
  <LoginRoute component={Login} path="/login" />
  <PublicRoute default component={Notfound} />

  <ProtectedRoute component={landingPage} path="/home" />
  <ProtectedRoute path="/" component={App} />
  <ProtectedRoute component={UserList} path="user" />
  <ProtectedRoute component={UserDetail} path="user/create" />
</Router>
```

i want this to be nested route with `user/:id`

```
<ProtectedRoute component={UserList} path="user" />
<ProtectedRoute component={UserDetail} path="user/create" />
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Feel like you're complicating things

```
const Routes = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.getItem('user_id') && setLoggedIn(true)
  }, [])

return (
  <Router>
    <LoginRoute component={Login} path="/login" />
    <Notfound default />

    {
      loggedIn 
      ? (
        <>
         <LandingPage path="/home" />
         <App path="/" component={App} />
         <UserList component={UserList} path="user">
           <UserDetail component={UserDetail} path="create" />
         </UserList>
        </>
       ) : (
        <Redirect from="" to="/login" noThrow />
       )
      }
     </Router>
  )
}
```

In case this didn't work as intended or you feel you want to use it in your way, do this

```
<Router>
  ...
  <ProtectedRoute component={UserList} path="user">
    <UserDetail path="create" />
  </ProtectedRoute>
</Router>
```

No need of using `ProtectedRoute` HOC for `UserDetail` since it's already nested under `ProtectedRoute`

and in `UserList` use `props.children` to render `UserDetail`